# Cloud Run: real world experience with custom domains and issue with latency

Tags: google-cloud-run

In researching Google's Cloud Run, one issue listed is:

> High request latency with custom domains when invoking from some
> regions

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#latency-domains

Unfortunately it does not say which regions, only ones from which it is *worse*. I assume very high is in the order of many seconds.

So:

a) is it the region the app is in, or the region the user is in? So like if an app is in eu-west1, and the user is in us-east4, does *that* result in high latency?

b) have people got some real world examples of numbers?

c) is the only way to avoid it (given the need for a custom domain) to proxy the request to it from a CDN? Alas Cloudflare does not let you send a custom hostname, but I assume others will. Though not sure if they would permit e.g. POST requests

Comment: This happends in all regions, it's just more significant in certain regions, the latency added to this depends on the region I've seen from 60ms to around 200ms but I've only tested within US regions. Basically an additional RTT is added to the latency for what I have seen.

Comment: Have you tried the [serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) within GCP?

Comment: @JoséSoní Thanks. I hadn't looked into that because I later found some test .app URLs and even without using a custom domain, the latency was surprisingly high. Even from my continent (by the suffix). So I figured any extra latency (from the domain) would be too slow in total. Not a true test, admittedly, as I don't know what people's random URLs are doing behind the scenes. But still disappointing. I need to do some more research

Comment: Anyone out there from GCP reading this: any plans to bring Cloud Run to the UK (europe-west-2 I believe you call it)? :) I rather suspect that may help with request times

Comment: I found this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/130681636) where other users asked for this, you can follow the issue so you get notifications when Google Updates the thread. also any ETA will be posted there.

Comment: @JoséSoní Ah, thanks. Didn't know about that page